# copying files mentioned in a file in the corresponding Paths in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

it's a python script.

I am writing the content of all the files with a  special extension to a txt file skipping the first line in files, removing duplicates and special Paths

```
import os
skipLines = "/home/YY"
mainDir = "C:/XX"
directory = os.fsencode(mainDir)
endFile = mainDir+"/endFile.txt"
open(endFile, 'w').close()
fileoutput = open(endFile, "a")
for file in os.listdir(directory):
    filename = os.fsdecode(file)
    fileFullPath = mainDir+"/"+filename
    if filename.endswith(".dep"):
        print("working on : ", filename)
        file = open(fileFullPath, "r")
        next(file)
        for line in file:
            if skipLines not in line:
                fileoutput.write(line)
    else:
        continue
    file.close()
fileoutput.close()

lines_seen = set()
with open("C:/XX/endFile.txt", "r+") as f:
    d = f.readlines()
    f.seek(0)
    for i in d:
        if i not in lines_seen:
            f.write(i)
            lines_seen.add(i)
    f.truncate()
fileoutput.close()
```

my end file looks like this:

F0/XXX.c 
../../F1/F2/X/Test.h 
../../F1/F2/Z/Test1.h 
../../../F1/F3/Y/Test3.h 
.
.
.

Here is my question:

how can I copy these file from the paths indicated in each line, and create a folder and create the same file path and copy the files in the corresponding paths?

Comment: Do you want to copy files in the list to a new folder?

Comment: Are these relative paths of the files you want to copy valid within the directory where you're running the script?

Comment: what I mean is that if I have ../../F1/F2/X/Test.h, then I want to create the same folder structure in a newly created folder and copy the test.h file into that path which is  ../../F1/F2/X/